# Benchmark test cases for DFT program or VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

**[Cross-posted on reddit/comp-chem](https://www.reddit.com/r/comp_chem/comments/o3h2od/benchmark_test_cases_for_dft_program_or_vasp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).**

I am trying to build my workflow of using DFT to predict properties of some materials, but I am not sure if I do it all right,  so I think there might be some benchmark test cases for the DFT program,  but it seems there are only some test cases for testing if the installation is right. I am not looking for a database of material properties, but a complete test case that includes every step of how to build the model.

My question is: **Where should I find a benchmark test case of my workflow?**

And if it is not possible to get a benchmark test case for all DFT programs, a test case just for VASP would be also helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perfect resource for this is [John Kitchin's "Modeling Materials Using Density Functional Theory" ebook](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/dft-book/dft.html). There are numerous real examples using VASP (and the Atomic Simulation Environment) that you can use to confirm you are setting up your workflow correctly.